# Modify for-counter inside a loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm trying to modify a counter in if loop because one array index number needs to be corresponded by the other in order for me to change the place of it's text, but the space between the strings add 1 to the counter.

```
for(int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++){

    if(isspace(p[i])){
        c1 = x[i-1];
        printf("%c", p[i]);
    }
    if(isalpha(p[i])){
        c1 = x[i];
        c2 = c1-96;
        printf("%c --- %c ---%d\n",p[i],c1, c2);
    }
```

This is one of the attempts but it made an infinite loop, I've tried different approach like:

```
    if(isspace(p[i))){
        printf("%c", p[i]);
        i -= 1;
    }
```

I even tried to see if 'i' counter really changes so i did:

```
    if(isspace(p[i])){
        printf("%c", p[i]);
        j = i;
        printf("%d\n", j);
        j = j -1;
        printf("%d\n", j);
```

which really showed that it goes one backwards, but once i make j = i; it flips to an infinity loop.

Comment: if `if(isspace(p[i]))` is `true` for `i=0 ` then `x[i-1]` is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: What is an "`if`-loop"?

Comment: x is an array that contains a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `i` is decremented for a space, but then incremented at the end of the loop, pointing still at the same space.  So it repeats infinitely.

EDIT:

```
// Off the top of my head, and untested,
// but you should be able to get the idea.
char* textString = "Test Test";
int sourceLen = strlen( textString );
for ( int srcIndex = 0, int destIndex = 0; srcIndex <= sourceLen ; srcIndex++ )
{
    if ( textString[ srcIndex ] != ' ' )
    {
        textString[ destIndex ] = textString[ srcIndex ]; // copies null terminator, too
        destIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if there is one space shouldn't it just decrements it once and go to the rest of the loop? I guess so fundamental understanding is lacking here.

Comment: @Dannz No because you decremented and the next loop it will test the same char that is the space. Then you re-decremtn it and go this way forever...

Comment: @LPs But if there is only one space shouldn't it just do it once?

Comment: If you are wanting to copy from an input string to an output string, modified, it is easy to use a `srcIndex` and `destIndex` maintained separately.

Comment: It may sound a little vague, But i wont to overwrite my string with other string that may have different length, but the space counts as 1 in the loop count which ruin everything for me.

Comment: @Dannz What I'm tring to explain: if string is`"Test Test"` when `i ==4` `isspace` is `true`. Then you move i back to `3v. Next loops will inc `i` to `4` and `isspace` will test p[4] forever

Comment: @LPs I finally learned something, So is it possible then to make the for loop to skip the count on the spaces?

Answer (score 1):

After you increment `i` inside the loop, it will be incremented again by the `for` construct. You can change the stop condition:

```
for(int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i >= n; i++) {
```

This way, if `i` is increased by more than one in the last iteration, the loop will still terminate.

This is because

```
for (CMD_1; COND; CMD_2) CMD_4
```

is equivalent to

```
CMD_1
if (COND) {
    CMD_4
    CMD_2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a while loop:

```
while(i < n ){

    if(isspace(p[i])){
        c1 = x[i-1];
        printf("%c", p[i]);
    }
    if(isalpha(p[i])){
        c1 = x[i];
        c2 = c1-96;
        printf("%c --- %c ---%d\n",p[i],c1, c2);
    }
}
```

and just add to i in whichever if you want it to increase

Comment: It still somehow makes an infinite loop that prints the same thing over and over again.

Comment: Do you add to the counter somewhere? Like Putting i++;  at the end of the loop?